# Matching Associations

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider the following matching:

```
p = Rule[_String, _String];
MatchQ[f[Rule["a", "b"], Rule["c", "d"]], f[p ..]]
(* True *)
```

If you replace `f` with `List` (or even outlandish operators like `Grid` or `SingularValueDecomposition`), it still matches:

```
MatchQ[List[Rule["a", "b"], Rule["c", "d"]], List[p ..]]
(* True *)
```

However, if you replace `f` with `Association`, it doesn't match:

```
MatchQ[Association[Rule["a", "b"], Rule["c", "d"]], Association[p ..]]
(* False *)
```

Why is this? Ordinarily I would suspect that evaluation changes the form, but calling `FullForm[Association[Rule["a", "b"], Rule["c", "d"]]]` returns `Association[Rule["a", "b"], Rule["c", "d"]]`, ie, its form is unchanged.

Ultimately I'd like a pattern that matches `Association`s of `String`s to `TemporalData`s, and while trying to figure out why my pattern didn't work, I found the above minimal(ish) example.

Comment: Association is a special construct. Use KeyValuePattern instead. And look up a bunch of WReach’s answers about Association.

Comment: Looks like `KeyValuePattern` was introduced in V10.4, but I'm on V10.2. ARGH

Comment: Then the best thing to do is to use _Association?someValidationFunction I think